# Why is there no path for PATCH using resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic nested route below.

```
resources :guides do
    resources :posts,    only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show]
end
```

This creates the following

```
guide_posts_path        POST    /guides/:guide_id/posts(.:format)           posts#create
new_guide_post_path     GET     /guides/:guide_id/posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
edit_guide_post_path    GET     /guides/:guide_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
guide_post_path         GET     /guides/:guide_id/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#show
                        PATCH   /guides/:guide_id/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
                        PUT     /guides/:guide_id/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
```

This worked fine for building the application and forms. But now I want to write a test for the edit page using mini test.

It comes to the point of sending a `PATCH` request to `posts#update` which I normally do by using the url path that points to the right controller like so.

```
patch update_guide_post_path(@guide, @post), post: { title:  "post title", post: "post content"}
```

In this case there is no `update_guide_post_path`, there is a path for everything else but update (by using `resources` in the routes file).

It can be done manually by making a separate route

```
match '/guides/:guide_id/posts/:id' => 'posts#update', :via => :patch, as: :update_guide_post_path
```

But I don't want to do that.

I've ran into this problem in the past and looking around I cant find an answer. Why is it only `update` that isn't given a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done with a `patch` request to `guide_post_path` as shown in the routes you listed.

So you want

```
patch guide_post_path(@guide, @post), post: { title:  "post title", post: "post content"}
```